# What should I do if I cannot install Python on cluster when using Apache Slider?

Tags: python, hadoop

It seems that Apache Slider requires Python on every machine in the cluster. However, for some reason I cannot setup Python on every machine.

I'm considering to upload a Python onto HDFS, then ask Slider to download it and set the PATH before executing my script. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: I used similar approach for installing another dependency for an mr job. It worked for me. In your case, the only condition is all of the cluster machine should be of same OS and with same set of libraries. Because the build version of python works only if the dependent libraries are available.

Comment: I've run into similar troubles and started building [knit](http://knit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. We have somehow fixed this issue by editing the source of Slider and re-compile it. I will briefly describe our fix when I'm free.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pyinstaller. This will pack your python script so you can run it everywhere without Python installed (it also packs all the dependencies). 
This is how I run my Apache Slider package that contains Python code.

http://www.pyinstaller.org/